# Setting a value for a key in a nested NSDictionary error (immutable)

Tags: objective-c

So I've got this code:

`self.items` is an `NSMutableArray`

```
    [self.items enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *checkin, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([checkin[@"_id"] isEqualToString:checkinID]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *checkin = (NSMutableDictionary *)self.items[index];
            NSMutableDictionary *user_data = (NSMutableDictionary *)checkin[@"user_data"];
            user_data[@"likes_checkin"] = @1;
            checkin[@"user_data"] = user_data;
            self.items[index] = checkin;
        }
    }];
```

But receive the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

1. I'm not sure how this error is occurring?
2. Is the approach I'm taking to do this the best way? It seems very verbose...

Comment: You have two different dictionaries declared as `checkin`. That will cause it's own problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the array *while* you are enumerating it and you are attempting to modify an immutable dictionary, not a mutable one.

If you are looking to modify just one dictionary in the array then first find the index of the dictionary you want to change and then change the dictionary outside of the enumeration:

```
__block NSUInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;
[self.items enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *checkin, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([checkin[@"_id"] isEqualToString:checkinID]) {
        foundIndex = index;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if (foundIndex != NSNotFound) {
    NSMutableDictionary *checkin = [self.items[foundIndex] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *user_data = [checkin[@"user_data"] mutableCopy];
    user_data[@"likes_checkin"] = @1;
    checkin[@"user_data"] = user_data;
    self.items[foundIndex] = checkin;
}
```

Comment: Cowardly downvoter: perhaps you'd like you explain the problem you have with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be casting immutable dictionaries to mutable dictionaries:

```
NSMutableDictionary *checkin = (NSMutableDictionary *)self.items[index];
```

That will not work. A cast will not actually alter the object and change it from an `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary`. This would:

```
NSMutableDictionary *checkin = [self.items[index] mutableCopy];
```

`mutableCopy`, when available, will make a new copy of the object that is mutable. Calling `mutableCopy` on an `NSDictionary` will result in a new `NSMutableDictionary` with the original dictionary's objects and keys.

Answer (score 0):

`self.items` is a `NSMutableArray` object but an item is `immutable` `NSDictionary`. You are adding an `NSDictionary` object inside `self.items`. Therefore add an `NSMutableDictionary` object to get `immutability`.

You can do so:

```
NSDictionary *yourImmutableDictionary = [NSDictionary doSomething];

NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:yourImmutableDictionary];
```

or

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDictionary = [yourImmutableDictionary mutableCopy];
```